Background service excecute more than 1 time at the same time runnnig
Im using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service lib.
i facing issue in the app.
when background service is ruuning. some time my service will be execute more 1 time at the same time. cause my data duplicated.
im using background service the get/app the date throught API.
main.dart
bool isrunning = false;
Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 5), (timer) async {
    if (!isrunning) {
      if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
        if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
          **foregroundServiceStartController.runService(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin).then((value) {
        isrunning = value;
          });**
        }
      }
    }

Function File:
Future<bool> runService(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin){
 try {
  if (!isRunning){
isRunning = true;
var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult ==           ConnectivityResult.wifi)
{isRunning = false;}
} else {isRunning = false;}
 } catch (error) {
      isRunning = false; 
 }
 return isRunning;
}

